# Cargar una imagen desde la base de datos con el evento MouseClicked de un jtable en Java

Tags: java

estoy empezando en java y me propuse a realizar una base de datos java y mysql, pero resulta que me quede en un punto que no se como solucionar. He buscado en foros y vídeos pero no encuentro la solución o el error.

Es una pequeña aplicación que registra un producto, y cada vez que registro un producto lo guarda en la base de datos. Los datos se cargan en jtable, al seleccionar una fila, estos se cargan en jtext. Lo que no logro es cargar la imagen (que esta en la base d datos) en un jlabel. El problema esta en el evento mousecliked del jtable

Desde ya, agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos.

```
package Presentacion;
```

import Configuracion.AdministradorConfiguracion;
import Datos.Producto;
import Datos.fechaTabla;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class gestionProducto extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Producto producto = new Producto();
    DefaultTableModel modelo;
    TableRowSorter jTblProductoFil;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    private FileInputStream fileImagen;
    private int longitudBytes;
    //FileInputStream fis;

```
public gestionProducto() 
{
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    cargarTabla();
}

private void ocultarColumnas(JTable tbl, int columna[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < columna.length; i++) 
    {
        tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(columna[i]).setMaxWidth(0);
        tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(columna[i]).setMinWidth(0);
        tbl.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(columna[i]).setMaxWidth(0);
        tbl.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(columna[i]).setMinWidth(0);
    }
}

private void cargarTabla()
{
    try 
    {
        Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
        CallableStatement obtenerProductos = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_productos()");
        ResultSet rs = obtenerProductos.executeQuery();
        jTblProducto.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new fechaTabla());
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        String titulos[]= {"Nro Producto","Producto","Stock","Precio Costo","Precio Venta","Marca","Categoria","Proveedor",
                          "Descripcion","Fecha Vencimiento","Meses Restantes","Dias Restantes","Imagen"};
        Object[] fila = new Object[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            fila[0] = rs.getInt("Nro Producto");
            fila[1] = rs.getString("Producto");
            fila[2] = rs.getInt("Stock");
            fila[3] = rs.getDouble("Precio Costo");
            fila[4] = rs.getDouble("Precio Venta");
            fila[5] = rs.getString("Marca");
            fila[6] = rs.getString("Categoria");
            fila[7] = rs.getString("Proveedor");
            fila[8] = rs.getString("Descripcion");
            fila[9] = rs.getDate("Fecha Vencimiento");
            fila[10] = rs.getInt("Meses Restantes");
            fila[11] = rs.getInt("Dias Restantes");
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob(13);
            if (blob != null) {
                byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
                try 
                {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);
                    fila[12] = new JLabel(icono);
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                fila[12] = "Sin imagen";
            }
            modelo.addRow(fila);
        }
        jTblProducto.setModel(modelo);
        //jTblProducto.setRowHeight(64);
        contarFilas();
        ocultarColumnas(jTblProducto, new int[]{0,3,4,5,6,7,8,12});
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener los productos:\n"
            + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

private void cargarTablaFil(String bus)
{
    try 
    {
        Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
        CallableStatement obtenerProductos = miComando.prepareCall("call buscar_producto(?)");
        ResultSet rs = obtenerProductos.executeQuery();
        jTblProducto.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new fechaTabla());
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        String titulos[]= {"Nro Producto","Producto","Stock","Precio Costo","Precio Venta","Marca","Categoria","Proveedor",
                          "Descripcion","Fecha Vencimiento","Meses Restantes","Dias Restantes","Imagen"};
        Object[] fila = new Object[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            fila[0] = rs.getInt("Nro Producto");
            fila[1] = rs.getString("Producto");
            fila[2] = rs.getInt("Stock");
            fila[3] = rs.getDouble("Precio Costo");
            fila[4] = rs.getDouble("Precio Venta");
            fila[5] = rs.getString("Marca");
            fila[6] = rs.getString("Categoria");
            fila[7] = rs.getString("Proveedor");
            fila[8] = rs.getString("Descripcion");
            fila[9] = rs.getDate("Fecha Vencimiento");
            fila[10] = rs.getInt("Meses Restantes");
            fila[11] = rs.getInt("Dias Restantes");
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob(13);
            if (blob != null) {
                byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
                try 
                {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);
                    fila[12] = new JLabel(icono);
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                fila[12] = "Sin imagen";
            }
            modelo.addRow(fila);
        }
        jTblProducto.setModel(modelo);
        //jTblProducto.setRowHeight(64);
        contarFilas();
        ocultarColumnas(jTblProducto, new int[]{0,3,4,5,6,7,8,12});
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener los productos:\n"
            + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

private void sumarColumnas()
{
    double sumatoria = 0;
    double sumatoria1 = 0;
    int totalRow = jTblProducto.getRowCount();
    totalRow -= 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (totalRow); i++) 
    {
        sumatoria = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(jTblProducto.getValueAt(i, 0)));
    }
    sumatoria1 += sumatoria;
    jTxtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(sumatoria1));
}

private void contarFilas() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= jTblProducto.getRowCount(); i++) 
    {
        jTxtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

private void jTblProductoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int filaSeleccionada = jTblProducto.getSelectedRow();
        modelo = (DefaultTableModel)jTblProducto.getModel();
        jTxtNombreProd.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 1).toString());
        jTxtStock.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 2).toString());
        jTxtPrecioCos.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 3).toString());
        jTxtPrecioVen.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 4).toString());
        jTxtMarca.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 5).toString());
        jTxtCategoria.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 6).toString());
        jTxtProveedor.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 7).toString());
        jTxtDescripcion.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 8).toString());
        JtxtFechaVen.setText(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 9).toString());

```
    if(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 12) != null)
    {
        ImageIcon ima = (ImageIcon)modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 12);
        Image imagen  = ima.getImage().getScaledInstance(jLblImagen.getWidth(),jLblImagen.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon imagen1 = new ImageIcon(imagen);
        jLblImagen.setIcon(imagen1);
    }
}                                         

private void jTxtBuscarKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
    jTxtBuscar.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
        {
            if (!jTxtBuscar.getText().isEmpty()) 
            {
                cargarTablaFil(jTxtBuscar.getText());
                contarFilas();
                ocultarColumnas(jTblProducto, new int[]{0,3,4,5,6,7,8,12});
            } 
            else 
            {
                cargarTabla();
                contarFilas();
                ocultarColumnas(jTblProducto, new int[]{0,3,4,5,6,7,8,12});
            }
        }
    });
    jTblProductoFil = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
    jTblProducto.setRowSorter(jTblProductoFil);
    jTblProducto.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
}                                   

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gestionProducto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gestionProducto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gestionProducto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gestionProducto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new gestionProducto().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextPane JtxtFechaVen;
private javax.swing.JButton jBtnEditar;
private javax.swing.JButton jBtnEliminar;
private javax.swing.JButton jBtnNuevo;
private javax.swing.JButton jBtnSalir;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblCategoria;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblDescripcion;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblFechaVen;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblImagen;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblMarca;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblPrecioCos;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblPrecioVen;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblProveedor;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblStock;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLblTotal;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPnlFicha;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPnlProducto;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane10;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane11;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane12;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane5;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane6;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane8;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane9;
private javax.swing.JTable jTblProducto;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtBuscar;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtCategoria;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtDescripcion;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtMarca;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtNombreProd;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtPrecioCos;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtPrecioVen;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtProveedor;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTxtStock;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTxtTotal;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Hola Charlees y bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Necesitamos código y en formato texto para poder probarlo. Además, queremos que nos expliques claramente qué has hecho, qué falla y qué quieres que sea el resultado. Más información en [ask].

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [help] y [ask]. Un par de apuntes a) No muestres tu código como pantallazos, inclúyelo como texto b) explica qué has intentado y porqué falla y c) haz las preguntas específicas y limitadas (por ejemplo, una con los problemas para recuperar una imagen de la bd y otra con los problemas para usar una imagen en un label).